# Qt - problems with query

Tags: mysql, qt, mariadb, heidisql

I have a problem with a query used with `MariaDB` in Qt program.
I state that all other queries in the program work fine.
This is the code that generates and execute the query:

```
   QSqlQuery Query;

   Query.prepare("SELECT d.*, dv.*, me.Descrizione FROM dipendenti d "
                  "LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM ("
                  "   SELECT *, row_number() over(partition by Dipendenti_Id order BY DataVisita desc) as rn "
                  "   FROM visitemediche) dv "
                  "   WHERE dv.rn = 1) dv ON d.id = dv.dipendenti_id "
                  "LEFT JOIN tipiscadenze t ON dv.TipiScadenze_id = t.Id "
                  "LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM ("
                  "  SELECT *, row_number() over(partition by Dipendenti_Id order by Dataformazione desc) as rn "
                  "  FROM mansioni) m "
                  "  WHERE m.rn = 1) m ON d.id = m.dipendenti_id "
                  "LEFT JOIN mansioni_elenco me ON m.Mansioni_Elenco_Id = me.id "
                  "LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM ("
                  "   SELECT *, row_number() over(partition by Dipendenti_Id order by DataDimissione DESC) as rn "
                  "   FROM assunzioni) a "
                  "   WHERE a.rn = 1) a ON a.dipendenti_id = d.Id "
                  "WHERE Cooperative_Id = :Cooperative_Id "
                  "AND dv.dataVisita IS NOT NULL "
                  "AND dv.tipovisita = :TipoVisita "
                  "AND a.dataassunzione IS NOT NULL AND datadimissione IS NULL "
                  "AND DATE_ADD(dv.DataVisita, INTERVAL t.Scadenza DAY) < :DataScadenza "
                  "GROUP BY d.Id");


    Query.bindValue(":Cooperative_Id", QString::number(ForYou::GetAziendaId()));
    Query.bindValue(":TipoVisita", "'"+cmbTipoVisita->currentData().toString()+"'");

    QDate DataScad = QDate::fromString(de->text(), "dd/MM/yyyy");
    Query.bindValue(":DataScadenza", "'"+DataScad.toString("yyyyMMdd")+"'");

    Query.exec();
```

The generated query from **Query.prepare** is this:

```
"SELECT d.*, dv.*, me.Descrizione FROM dipendenti d LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM (   SELECT *, row_number() over(partition by Dipendenti_Id order BY DataVisita desc) as rn    FROM visitemediche) dv    WHERE dv.rn = 1) dv ON d.id = dv.dipendenti_id LEFT JOIN tipiscadenze t ON dv.TipiScadenze_id = t.Id LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM (  SELECT *, row_number() over(partition by Dipendenti_Id order by Dataformazione desc) as rn   FROM mansioni) m   WHERE m.rn = 1) m ON d.id = m.dipendenti_id LEFT JOIN mansioni_elenco me ON m.Mansioni_Elenco_Id = me.id LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM (   SELECT *, row_number() over(partition by Dipendenti_Id order by DataDimissione DESC) as rn    FROM assunzioni) a    WHERE a.rn = 1) a ON a.dipendenti_id = d.Id WHERE Cooperative_Id = 1 AND dv.dataVisita IS NOT NULL AND dv.tipovisita = 'O' AND a.dataassunzione IS NOT NULL AND datadimissione IS NULL AND DATE_ADD(dv.DataVisita, INTERVAL t.Scadenza DAY) < '20210703' GROUP BY d.Id"
```

and if I try it in **HeidiSQL** it works fine, but executed from Qt the result of **Query.size()** is always == 0.

The query result has no erros:

```
qDebug() << "Errors: " << Query.lastError();
```

and the result is:

```
Errors:  QSqlError("", "", "") ""
```

I don't understand the problem.
Maybe can be a too long query?

Comment: Did you check if all the parameters are getting their expected value ?  Without data, and without knowing which data should be produced by the query this is an impossible question.

Answer (score 0):

I found a problem.
It generates from this line:

```
Query.bindValue(":DataScadenza", "'"+DataScad.toString("yyyyMMdd")+"'");
```

I changed it in:

```
Query.bindValue(":DataScadenza", DataScad.toString("yyyyMMdd"));
```